# convert from polynomial to normal base in GF(2^5)

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I want to convert between the polynomial (standard) base to a type II optimal normal base.
for example take the field GF($2^5$) with the irreducible polynomal $p(x) = x^5+x^4+x^3+x+1$. In polynomial base I have an element represented as $a_0\alpha^0+a_1\alpha^2 + ... + a_4\alpha^4$, in normal base as $b_0\alpha^1 + b_1\alpha^2 + b_2\alpha^4 ... + b_4\alpha^{16}$.
So I wanted to calculate the conversion matrix $M$ satisfying the equation $a = M * b$, where $a$ and $b$ are vectors of the coefficients $a_0, a_1 ... $.
I thought that the columms of $M$ were the representation of the elements $\alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^4, ..., \alpha^{16}$ mod $p(x)$. So my matrix $M$ was the following.
$$ M = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 1 &0 &0 &1 &0 \\ 0 &1 &0 &1 &0 \\ 0 &0 &0 &1 &1 \\ 0 &0 &1 &0 &1 }$$
To convert back I used the inverse of $M$. However as it turned out the conversion is not working properly. I tried to verify it by taking to random elements $c, d$ and multiplying it in the polynomial base and converting the result to normal base and comparing it to the result of representations of $c,d$ in normal base multiplied with a normal base multiplier. The multiplier are working correctly, they were used before. Sometimes I get the same result, sometimes I don't. 
Maybe my mistake is to assume that $\alpha$ is the same for both bases?
I hope you can understand my text as I am not used to mathematic formalism.

Thank you!

Comment: You definitely need to make sure that the $\alpha$ generating your normal basis is also a root of $p(x)$. What is the description of the normal basis in this case? I have a vague recollection that it might be the relative trace of an eleventh root of unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat speculative, because I don't trust my memory 100% about the structure of an optimal normal basis in this case (and you didn't describe it either).

I make the assumption that an optimal normal basis is constructed as follows. Let $\beta$ be a primitive eleventh root of unity. Then $\beta$ generates a normal basis for $GF(2^{10})$. The element $\alpha$ is then gotten as the relative trace of $\beta$:
$$
\alpha=\beta+\beta^{32}=\beta+\beta^{-1}.
$$
As 
$$\alpha^5=\alpha^4\alpha=(\beta^4+\beta^{-4})(\beta+\beta^{-1})=
\beta^5+\beta^3+\beta^{-3}+\beta^{-5}
$$
we easily see that
$$
\alpha^5+\alpha^4+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=\sum_{k=-5}^5\beta^k=0.
$$
Thus the minimal polynomial of this $\alpha$ is $r(x)=x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1$, i.e. the reciprocal of your $p(x)$.

To check that that we are talking about the same normal basis let us calculate the multiplication table of this one. So let's denote $\gamma_j=\alpha^{2^j}$ for $j=0,1,2,3,4$. Keeping in mind that $\beta^{11}=1$ we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\gamma_0&=\beta+\beta^{-1}\\
\gamma_1&=\beta^2+\beta^{-2}\\
\gamma_2&=\beta^4+\beta^{-4}\\
\gamma_3&=\beta^8+\beta^{-8}=\beta^{-3}+\beta^3\\
\gamma_4&=\beta^{16}+\beta^{-16}=\beta^5+\beta^{-5}.
\end{aligned}
$$
It suffices to find the effect of multiplication by $\gamma_0$
as the others are gotten by shifting cyclically. The rule is
$$
(\beta+\beta^{-1})(\beta^k+\beta^{-k})=(\beta^{k+1}+\beta^{-(k+1)})+
(\beta^{k-1}+\beta^{-(k-1)}).
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
\gamma_0\cdot\gamma_0&=\gamma_1,\\
\gamma_0\cdot\gamma_1&=\gamma_0+\gamma_3,\\
\gamma_0\cdot\gamma_2&=\gamma_3+\gamma_4,\\
\gamma_0\cdot\gamma_3&=\gamma_1+\gamma_2,\\
\gamma_0\cdot\gamma_4&=\gamma_2+\gamma_4.
\end{aligned}
$$
We got the hoped for $9=2\cdot5-1$ terms, so this normal basis is an optimal one.

In terms of the monomial basis given by $\alpha$, the elements of this normal basis are:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\gamma_0&=\alpha,\\
\gamma_1&=\alpha^2,\\
\gamma_2&=\alpha^4,\\
\gamma_3&=\alpha^3+\alpha,\\
\gamma_4&=\alpha^5+\alpha^3+\alpha=\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1.
\end{aligned}
$$

Can you try again with these, and report back?

Comment: Thank you for your input! I I tried with your values, but sadly it doesn't work. For instance I tried with $a = x$ and $b = x^4$ so $c = x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$. In normal base I have $a_n = x$ and $b_n = x^4$ so $c_n = x^8 + x^{16}$. However if I try to convert $c$ to the normal base I get $x + x^2 + x^{16}$. Unfortunately not the result I hoped for...

Comment: @Paul: What I was saying that if your normal basis is the same as mine, then $c=a\cdot b=\alpha^5=\alpha^4+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=\gamma_3+\gamma_4=x^8+x^{16}$. Same as with your normal basis! In other words you still used the wrong polynomial as a minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. To reiterate
$$x^5=x^4+x^2+x+1$$ NOT $x^4+x^3+x+1$ as you seem to think.

Comment: oh... yes you are right! thank you :) so if I want to convert between a polynomial and a normal base I can't choose the irreducible polynomial? or is there maybe another way?

Comment: That's correct. The irreducible polynomial must have the elements of the normal basis as zeros. IIRC if you construct an optimal normal basis with the algorithm given in *Handbook of Cryptography* it is not too difficult to find that polynomial. Well, basically you need to expand
$$p(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^2)\cdots(x-\alpha^{2^{n-1}})$$ and there it is! In the above example I used shortcut, but I have collected a bit of experience in spotting such shortcuts over the years :-).
For special normal bases (like the one given by $\beta$ in my example, the minimal polynomial is known.

Comment: ok I'm starting to understand! thank you very much, you helped me a lot!

Comment: I hope I am not too annoying, but I have another follow up question... I read in some paper that a type II ONB corresponds to a polynomial base with the double length: (http://dna.cs.byu.edu/papers/pdf/mascots.pdf - page 3). However it does not clearly state how the conversion is done. Do you maybe happen to know this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the normal basis, you usually (always?) need to base it on an element $\beta$ that is not $\alpha$.  For your field, you can use

$\beta = \alpha^3$

basis vector: $b_0\beta^1 + b_1\beta^2 + b_2\beta^4 + b_3\beta^8 + b_4\beta^{16} $